# Getting Bad Request error while updating email category with Office 365 API and HttpClient in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, httprequest, dotnet-httpclient, office365api

I'm trying to to update email category and also mark it as read after that with the help of `Outlook 365 API` and `HttpClient`. Following [this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations#UpdateAMessage).

In the tutorial the code is as below to update category and mark as read but, I'm not getting that how should I attach these details to `HttpClient` and request.

```
PATCH https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/AAMkAGE0Mz8S-AAA=
Content-Type: application/json

{
"Categories": [
"Orange category",
"Green category"
],
"IsRead": true
}
```

The method and HttpClient I'm using are as below:

**Update 1**

```
public string UpdateCategory(AuthenticationResult result, string mediator)
    {
    //HTTPMethod.PATCH not available to adding it manualy.
    var httpMethod = new HttpMethod("PATCH");
    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(httpMethod, mediator);
    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
    //JSON in a string variable for test
    var tempJson = @"{""Categories"" : ""Checking""}";
    Converting string to JSON
    var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tempJson);
    //Adding the JSON to request.Content
    request.Content =new StringContent(jsonData,Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;
    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
     throw new WebException(response.StatusCode.ToString() + ": " + response.ReasonPhrase);
    mediator = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    return mediator;
    }
```

It's throwing `Bad Request` error.

I am using 365 API with a WPF application. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got solution. Here it is for newbies like me.

**What was the error -**

When I request API with PATCH with body I was getting `Bad Request` error.

**What I was doing wrong -**

When I evaluated my request with [this](https://oauthplay.azurewebsites.net/) awesome tool for testing outlook 365 API, I come to know the error which was

```
"error": {
    "code": "RequestBodyRead",
    "message": "An unexpected 'PrimitiveValue' node was found when reading from the JSON reader. A 'StartArray' node was expected."
}
```

This error meant I was sending wrong data. I was sending `string` to a `List<string>`. This is really silly I know but it happens right? ;)

So, to correct this instead of passing JSON as fixed string, I created a class with a `List<string>` property as below to have flexibility to input category as want.

```
public class ChangeEmailCategory
{
    public List<string> Categories { get; set; }

}
```

And here is final method.

```
//Passing parameters - AuthenticationResult, URI with authentication header, List of categories.
public string UpdateCategory(AuthenticationResult result, string uriString,List<string> categories)
    {
        //HTTPMethod.PATCH not available so adding it manualy.
        var httpMethod = new HttpMethod("PATCH");
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(httpMethod, uriString);
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
        ChangeEmailCategory cec = new ChangeEmailCategory();
        cec.Categories = categories;
        //Serializing class properties as JSON
        var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cec);
        //Adding JSON to request body
        request.Content =new StringContent(jsonData,Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.SendAsync(request).Result;
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            throw new WebException(response.StatusCode.ToString() + ": " + response.ReasonPhrase);
        return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
```

Here is method call.

```
List<string> categories = new List<string>();
categories.Add("Checking");
//utility is my class containing method
utility.UpdateCategory(result, categoryChangeUri, categories);
```

That's all! It took me one day to learn and figure it out. Thanks to all posts on Stack Overflow and google which I referred but not remember not to mention here.

If anyone need any additional information regarding this do let me know. Just mention me in comments. I will try to help.