# An unexpected 'PrimitiveValue' node was found when reading from the JSON reader. A 'StartArray' node was expected

Tags: powershell, graph

I have an Azure AD Application where I need to add an extra appRole in the appRoles section within the service principal with Powershell. I use an Invoke-RestMethod to the Graph API with the following API Url: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/AppID

The Invoke-RestMethod returns an PSCustomObject, and then I add another PSCustomObject in the appRoles section. I then convert the PSCustomObject to JSON and want to write back the JSON to the service principal. The problem is when I want to write the JSON back to the service principal I get the error message:

> Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

I've tried to do this also with the Graph explorer and then I get the error message:

> "An unexpected 'PrimitiveValue' node was found when reading from the JSON reader. A 'StartArray' node was expected."

I think the same problem is also here in C#: [Getting Bad Request error while updating email category with Office 365 API and HttpClient in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42808408/getting-bad-request-error-while-updating-email-category-with-office-365-api-and/42839806#42839806)

When I do a Get in Graph Explorer the every appRole is displayed like this:

```
{
  "allowedMemberTypes": [
    "User"
  ],
  "description": "TEST-ALLOWALL",
  "displayName": "TEST-ALLOWALL",
  "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000",
  "isEnabled": true,
  "origin": "ServicePrincipal",
  "value": "ARNROLEVALUE"
},
```

When I do an Invoke-RestMethod and then ConvertTo-Json, every appRole is displayed like this:

```
{
  "allowedMemberTypes":  "User",
  "description":  "TEST-ALLOWALL",
  "displayName":  "TEST-ALLOWALL",
  "id":  "00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000",
  "isEnabled":  true,
  "origin":  "ServicePrincipal",
  "value":  "ARNROLEVALUE"
},
```

How can I make sure the Invoke-RestMethod keeps the allowedMemberTypes value type an array/list like ["User"] instead of the value "User"?

And how can I make my own PSCustomObject allowedMembertypes value and arraylist so I can add it to the service principal?

This is the code I am using

```
$apiUrl = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/servicePrincipals/000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000'
$Data = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $graphAPIReqHeader -Uri $apiUrl -Method Get

$obj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name allowedMemberTypes -Value "User"
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name description -Value $RoleName
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name displayName -value $RoleName
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name id -value $Id
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name isEnabled -value "true"
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name origin -value "ServicePrincipal"
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name value -value $Value

$Data.appRoles += $obj
$NewJson = $Data | ConvertTo-Json
$NewData = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $graphAPIReqHeader -Uri $apiUrl -Body $NewJson -Method Patch -ContentType 'application/json'
```

Comment: Checkout the `-depth` parameter of convert-json. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-6

Comment: Thanks Moerwald! It works for the PsCustomObject i've received with Invoke-RestMethod with ConvertTo-Json -Depth 4.

But how can I also create an string array for the PSCustomObject I want to add?
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name allowedMemberTypes -Value "User"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$input = @"
{
  "allowedMemberTypes": [
    "User"
  ],
   "description": "TEST-ALLOWALL",
   "displayName": "TEST-ALLOWALL",
  "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000",
  "isEnabled": true,
  "origin": "ServicePrincipal",
  "value": "ARNROLEVALUE"
}
"@

$jObject = $input | convertfrom-json

$psObj = [Pscustomobject] @{
   AllowedMemberTypes = $jObject.allowedMemberTypes 
}
 $psObj.AllowedMemberTypes.Gettype()
```

`$psObj.AllowedMemberTypes.Gettype()` shows that `AllowedMemberTypes` is of type array.

You can find the code [online](https://tio.run/##dVGxTsMwEN3zFSerA0gkKisSUjJELKGp2hSGqkOaHNSRY1u2E1RBvz04xi2VAjecbL/37s7vpPhApQ/I2DDMKJedgUeISQA2Pl0GICVjllY/Y7tHVRwlavIAW49afKNREX/d3Z3fSY26UlQaKrjlkyJdF2GSZfmrTeSKRrVk5XFRtvg/jdB6BOc@wj/SGFd8nfJyz3CUGdXhBRCKvlM30BpVTytcKsorKkv2K@5L1rlhktVilWfpS5JtUvfDEwQkDhxv1uT7BqvRMO/cF1SC96jMmxJt2GjBIaxRmgPcz71Gaiuyiu1SV502ohWuxg7is9uQTNweO/hm0XQX4ISnyzp@ekTTMtETGmMPN7fBMHwD), and play around with it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I works ok now. Only thing I had to do was to remove -depth 10 . Seems that ConvertFrom-Json doesn't have to Depth parameter, only ConvertTo-Json